# Get public post from Facebook's Graph Search API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am new to Facebook APIs. I am using Graph Search API and want to get public post such as comments, status updates who are having conversation about an object (could be a thing, location, personality etc).

I have valid access token with me.

Is it possible? How?

Any solution is welcome.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**UPDATE**:

Public post search is no longer available from API version >=2.0.

Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search

---

**Original Answer**:

Yes, of course it's possible.

You can search over all public objects (posts, users, pages, groups) using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=<token>q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE
```

Facebook search API is pretty easy to use. I would suggest you to read the [documentation for the Search API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/). I will also recommend using [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=search?q=watermelon&type=post) for trying out your queries.

Comment: Please make sure you have the appropriate Access Token for the respective endpoints as described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/search/#access_tokens 

To search for Pages and Groups, you need an App Token, for all other a valid User Token.

Comment: note that in v2.0 of the Graph API, support for searching public posts was removed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_graph_api

Comment: it's deprecated

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search refers to a blank page or not related content

Answer (score 3):

As an update, I would mention that public post search are no longer available from API version >=2.0.

See docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.0#search

Answer (score 0):

I can get this to work but I have NEWT level question;

If I search for `q=101class&type=post` then it gives me a response of `data[]`.

However if I put in text ONLY such as `q=apples&type=post` it works fine.

Answer (score -2):

Post search is not directly supported, instead you should use this call:

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/12345678912345?fields=posts.limit(5)`

You can use that call with access token from the graph explorer, where the long number represents a page ID